# List files in a folder to a JOptionPane

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java-io

Lately I have been working on a program to list the files in a folder so they show up on a `JOptionPane`.

I have tried to get a `File[]` by calling `File.listFiles` on the folder object, but it results  a `NullPointerException` on line `for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {`.

The code I have is this:

```
if (OS.contains("Mac")){
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                File folder = new File("/Users/"+ user +"/Desktop");

                File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
                String herd = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(2000);
                      String s = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                      herd = sb.append(s).append(", ").toString();
                }

                msgbox(herd);

            }
        });
    }
```

msgbox is:

```
public void msgbox(String s){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s);
}
```

The `NullPointerException` stack trace is the following:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at goatSoftware.CreateJFrame$1.actionPerformed(CreateJFrame.java:93)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: does this code help?

Comment: `herd = sb.append(s).append(", ").toString();` Here, you're ignoring the "old" value of `herd` and overwrite it with a new string. Btw: please add the exception stacktrace.

Comment: It certainly does, thank you. If there's an error, post the stacktrace too, it's a valuable information.

Comment: Which line is line 93 in `CreateJFrame.java`?

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem That means that `listOfFiles` is `null`. Please read this [JavaDoc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) to check in which cases the `listFiles` method returns `null`. Also consider using [`Path`](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/listing_directory_contents_with_jdk) since the new API is much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(OS.contains("Mac"))

{
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String path = "/Users/" + user + "/Desktop";
            File folder = new File(path);

            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            if (listOfFiles != null && listOfFiles.length > 0) {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(2000);
                for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                    String s = listOfFiles[i].getName();
                    sb.append(s).append(", ");
                }
                msgbox(sb.toString());

            } else {
                msgbox("No files in the folder " + path);
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

#### The errors in your initial code:

1. You declared the StringBuffer inside the for loop. On each loop a new object was constructed.
2. Don't need to do sb.toString() on each loop. It's usually done once.
3. File.listFiles() may return `null` for an invalid path. So the falue of `listOfFiles` should be evaluated for `null`.

#### What needs to be improved:

1. Different messages for "invalid path" and "empty directory". Right now it's all the same, but it should not be.
2. The trailing comma! For a valid directory with some files the output will be: "a, b, c,". The last comma is unnecessary. You have to avoid or delete it somehow and it's a separate (and a quite popular) question. Good luck with it. )

Comment: I still get the same stacktrace saying that the error came from line 93. Which is: if (listOfFiles != null & listOfFiles.length > 0) {

Comment: I'll try it as soon as eclipse launches

Comment: @TheWrenchintheSystem I've added some ideas for further improvement. Maybe it will be interesting )

Answer (score 1):

Can you map the line number to the line in code where exception is coming? It may have nothing to do with the JOptionPane.

I suspect NPE might be coming on this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
```

when an invalid folder is being listed. File.listFiles() can return null.

Comment: Well, then before running the for loop, you can check if the listOfFiles is null and give an error message instead to user. Something like "Could not read contents of folder ...."

Comment: it is in fact null. I suspect it may be the permissions

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the JFrame  object to the method.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(urJFrameObject, s);
```

If the class having msgBox( ) function extends JFrame then change the code like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s);
```

Comment: Yes, it does extend it.

Comment: Then instead of null pass 'this'  that is the object of the class in that show MessageDialog method as specified in the answer

Comment: I did, nothing different

Comment: Change your code from public void msgbox(String s){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s); } to: public void msgbox(String s){ JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, s); }

Comment: yep it is. But I still have the problem with the sb variable

Comment: Try changing the capacity of it

Comment: Why not try some thing like this : String s=""; s+=","+ listOfFiles[i].getName();

Comment: where should I put that?

Comment: Instead of a string builder object using only a string variable...like in the above comment

Comment: there is no append method for strings

Comment: Declare the string var outside the for loop and give a value s=""

Comment: Then inside for loop, s = s + "," + listFiles[i].getName();